# What is the correct way to implement Significant Motion Sensor?

Tags: android, significant-motion-sensor

I placed Significant Motion Sensor code from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion#sensors-motion-significant in my activity. But the app crashes as soon as it is launched. What is the correct way to implement Significant Motion Sensor?

Comment: Also mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION,true); returns null.

Comment: Please add logcat error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION,true);
```

returns null it's pretty likely that your device does not support this sensor.
You should consider to use Accelerator directly as alternative.